# Should [java] be removed from certain [scala] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Often I see [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) questions dubiously tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) as well. Currently there are 2,825 questions [with both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+scala).
 Here is an example of one that I feel shouldn't be tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java):

- [println _ in Scala: Why is the type () => Unit instead of (Any) => Unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817012/println-in-scala-why-is-the-type-unit-instead-of-any-unit)

Of course, there are some where the tag does arguably make sense, for example:

- [Pattern matching on POJOs in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832697/pattern-matching-on-pojos-in-scala)

For posts of the first form, two questions:

1. The main question: Is [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) inappropriate?
2. If so, should I bother removing the tags on older questions, or just ignore them so they don't get bumped and keep an eye out in the future instead?

Comment: I'd say be very careful.  There are some legitimate Scala-only questions there, some legitmate Java-only questions there, and some questions that should be closed/deleted.  Otherwise, I'm on board with it.

Comment: I think the actual problem is that [tag:jvm] wasn't used more.

Comment: It is likely many of them should have [java] replaced with [jvm]

Comment: @BAR: I only looked at the first page (50 Qs), but I don't see more than maybe 3 questions that are related to the JVM. Most of them are straight Scala questions and thus should be tagged just [tag:scala], some are about Java/Scala or Scala/Java interop and should be tagged with [tag:java] as well, but [tag:jvm] would be inappropriate for pretty much all of them. The vast majority of the Java/Scala questions would apply equally well when running on Dalvik or GWT, for example, and thus are unrelated to the JVM.

Comment: I feel the same way as @Jörg re: [tag:jvm]. That tag should be used with [tag:scala] in only very specific contexts (similar to how [tag:jvm] with [tag:java] is valid only in very specific contexts). I wouldn't tag either of my linked questions as [tag:jvm], for example.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You can always edit the question and remove the tag to fix it

Answer (score 4):

> Should [java] be removed from certain [scala] questions?

Lets do the test:

- Is my question about [java]?
- Can [java] work as the only tag on the question?

If any of those is "no", then yeah, remove the java tag from where is not relevant. If it's relevant, then leave it.

Comment: That makes sense. Just to clarify, the second point would exclude the *vast* majority (I would imagine) of the questions with both tags; i.e. anything where the syntax / structure of Scala is a part of the question. Was that your intent?

Comment: @JasonC defer to the first point. "Is my question relevant to java or is just incidental/tangential to my issue?"